# Is there a way to configure Angular 2/4 environment in eclipse without any plugins?

Tags: eclipse, angular

I need to configure eclipse with Angular 2/4 environment. I tried with Angular IDE Plugins by
**1.** Genuitec,LLC Commerial pack but its paid so not supporting for development longer than 8-10 days.
**2.** Webeclipse its not giving full functionality again.
**3.** Angular Eclipse by Angelo ZERR, it only supports for Angular 1.x.x.

Can anyone help me on this.
Thanks in advance..

Comment: Angelo ZERR has also a plugin which supports angular2+ (there are two, one for angularjs and the other for angular2+). Works quite well.

Comment: Yea. This is right but for this Angelo ZERR plugin we need to add npm and angular 2+ globally.

Comment: You can configure installation pathes of nodejs and angular cli in your eclipse preferences...